# Juju vm's in vsphere fail to boot when vmware hardware definition is updated above version 10

Tags: boot, grub2, vmware

Juju deploys vms to vsphere with version 10 hardware definition.  The boot sequence seems to die configuring the video drivers for the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/etc/default/grub contains:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty1 console=ttyS0"

If I remove the "console=tty1 console=ttyS0"

and rebuild the /boot/grub/grub.cfg to include this change then I can upgrade the hardware definition and reboot just fine.

Comment: I also needed to remove the "console=tty1 console=ttyS0" string from /etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg and run update-grub.